# Help with Android App Idea

Tags: android

Being a starter in Android programming, I would like to ask some help here regarding my idea to create an app. For example, there is a list of sign language pictures on my application from a-z, how can I put an output text on a textfield when i click on the picture..i know this is a basic question but it would be very helpful to me if someone helped me..:) thank you..and happy new year:)

Comment: Happy New Year!  FYI, usually including the code that you want help with will help out quite a bit.  When you can display that you've already started working on the project, more people will be willing to help, and they will better understand how to help you.

Answer (score 4):

I would heartily suggest heading to [Google's Android Developers Page](http://developer.android.com/index.html).  A large amount of resources are available, including sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to bind to the onClick() method of your images and speficy an onClickListener object that updates the TextView/EditText.

Answer (score 1):

Just to toss this out there ... if you have not checked out [**Google's Android App Inventor**](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/) yet then definitely take a moment to see the tools they have freely available. Along with the tools they have several neat [**tutorials**](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/learn/tutorials/index.html) that might help spark app ideas.

Comment: App Inventor is now under the guidance of MIT, and the name has been changed to MIT App Inventor.  It can be found at http://www.appinventor.mit.edu/ .

Answer (score 0):

If your list of images is being managed by an adapter, match the list with a list or array of names which you can then use to update the TextView by using the position of the image clicked in the list. I use a similar approach with a Gallery of icons and a TextView :

```
final TextView name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.imageChosen);
    name.setText(mImageNames[mInitialImage]);

    g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {               
            name.setText(mImageNames[position]);
            mListener.imageChanged(position);
            dismiss();
        }
    });
```